# How to name a class with method register()? Registerer/Registrator/Registrar?

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

I assume either option is correct: Registerer/Registrator/Registrar. So the question is not only about English. I want to address software developers.

How would you as an English speaker / employee in English speaking company name the class?

Example:

```
class SomethingRegisterer {
    func register(something: Something) { ... }
}
```

Usage example: registration of dependencies, registration of request handlers, etc.

If you think that it is an inappropriate question for this site, because of its subjective nature, let me know. But it is a real problem that is eating me from the inside (as well as my PR reviewers).

Comment: Did my answer help? what did you end up naming your class?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the postfix "[Registrar](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/registrar)" as it is "an official responsible for keeping a register or official records." (as defined by the Oxford dictionary) e.g.

```
class EmployeeRegistrar {
    func register(employee: Employee) { ... }
}
```

The other two names (i.e. Registerer and Registrator) are much more unusual in use.